# Omitted for loop values

Tags: c++

It's my first post here and my first time with C++. I'm looking at some code I got from the Internet but I have a question about it.

It has a for loop, like this:

```
for(cin >> t;t--;)
```

I understand what it's doing, but I can't understand what the condition is.

According to this format, `for ( init; condition; increment )`, `t--` is the condition, but it doesn't make much sense. I think that `t--` is the increment, but why is it the second parameter?

Shouldn't it be something like: `for (cin >> t; ;t--);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--` operator is an "decrement and return" operator. Since it is used as postdecrement, it returns `t` and then decrement the value.

In C++ everything that is different from 0 is `true` and viceversa so basically it's equivalent to

```
t == 0
```

Of course things would be different in case of `--t`, since it would decrement the value before and then return it (it would end the loop one iteration earlier).

Comment: `t--` returns `t` and simultaneously sets `t = t - 1`.  You're thinking pf prefix.  Thus, the last decrement will be the decrement of 1 to 0, which returns 1, continuing the loop one last time for `t = 0`.

Comment: Hmmm, so with t-- in the condition position, we are both decrementing it's value and evaluating the condition?

Comment: It is not evaluated, it is returned. It's a numerical value but in C++ a number can be a condition indeed.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. It's basically the same as:

for (t=input; t>0; t--);

right?

Comment: @Wug the last decrement will be 0 to either undefined or the maximum value of the type (if unsigned). And no @bex it's not the same. `t--` is executed at the end of the loop body, not at the start. It's the same as `for (cin >> t; t != 0; ) {t--; <body>} t--;`

Comment: I meant the last decrement that actually got looped over.

Answer (score 0):

`for ( init; condition; increment )` is just the recommended way to use for loops. The real way for loops work is:

```
for(
    <runs once before loop>;
    <check before every iteration, loop if true/non-zero>;
    <run after every iteration>)
```